# POST request with form data fails after switching from request-promise to node-fetch

Tags: node.js, request, form-data, node-fetch

I've replaced `request-promise` with `node-fetch`. Everything works well except for one request, which sends form data to an endpoint that I, unfortunately, can't provide here. This is the code that works with `request-promise`:

```js
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: keys.endpointUrl,
    formData: {
        operations: JSON.stringify(operations),
        map: JSON.stringify(map)
    },
    json: true
};

const response = await request(options);
```

After moving to `node-fetch`, it looks like so:

```js
const FormData = require('formdata-node');

const form = new FormData();

form.set('operations', JSON.stringify(operations));
form.set('map', JSON.stringify(map));

const opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: form
};

const res = await fetch(keys.endpointUrl, opts);

console.log(res);

const response = res.json();
```

`res` is logged as:

```js
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _transformState: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    status: 500,
    statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] }
  }
}
```

I tried to add different headers but unfortunately, it keeps failing. What am I missing?

NodeJS: v12.16.1
node-fetch: 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need to set the `content-type` header to `x-www-form-urlencoded`, which your endpoint is probably expecting. Note in the [documentation](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/tree/ca50c22e3410ee288a7b4a8a89384d6df95ae3b6#post-with-form-parameters):

> The Content-Type header is only set automatically to x-www-form-urlencoded when an instance of URLSearchParams is given as such:

Answer (score 0):

You don't need FormData unless you are uploading files

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var form = {
  "operations": JSON.stringify(operations),
  "map": JSON.stringify(map)
}

const opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: form
};

const res = await fetch(keys.endpointUrl, opts);
```